# Angular calls services twice

Tags: angular

```
 getPersonalMast(name:string){
        console.log("patient");
          this.masterDataService.getPersonalMast(this.staff).subscribe( console.log("Inside subscribe"), response => this.staffInfo = response);
          return this.staffInfo;
    }
```

THis is the master service called

```
getPersonalMast(personName: String): Observable<PersonalMastModel[]>{
console.log("patientInfo");
        let headers = new Headers();        
            if(personName!= undefined){
                headers.append(AppUtils.HEADER_AUTHENTICATION, localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN));
                headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
             return this.http.post(AppUtils.GET_PERSONAL_MASTER_URL ,{personName:personName},{headers:headers})

              .map( console.log("Inside map"),response => response.json().result)
               .catch(this.handleError);
            }
    }
```

Having this service, Each time invoking this service causes hitting the url multiple times.

Each method call = multiple service call.

Why this happen and how can I solve this ?

Invoking the service code :

```
  <input  ng2-auto-complete 
                    [(ngModel)]="staff"                
                    [source]="staffInfo"
                    placeholder="enter text"
                    [list-formatter]="listFormatter"
                    value-property-name="perscode"
                    display-property-name="personName"
                    (keypress)="getPersonalMast($event)"
                    >
```

Comment: Can you show the code for invoking the service?

Comment: Does the service get called exactly 2 times each time the component loads, or does it get called once the first time, twice the second time, three times the third time etc. when you reload the window, or revisit this component?

Comment: @DeborahK updated the question

Comment: @Stephen R. Smith : every time it calls twice

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your inclusion of the html/template code.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this behavior is a result of subscribing to Observables and not unsubscribing when you destroy the component, so the subscription persists and when the component loads again, the Observable responds multiple times to the component request. These subscriptions accumulate.

To prevent this, and to prevent memory leaking, you should unsubscribe to the Observable when you destroy each component.

Add these imports to your component

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Add this in your class - I usually do this above the constructor.

```
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>()
```

Add an ngOnDestroy function

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

And then add this immediately before your .subscribe

```
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
```

So in your case, it would look like this.

getPersonalMast(name:string){
        console.log("this.staff "+JSON.stringify(this.staff));

```
this.masterDataService.getPersonalMast(this.staff)
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(response => this.staffInfo = response);
      return this.staffInfo;
}
```

So what happens is the subscribe will remain active until you navigate away from the component, at which point ngOnDestroy fires which unsubscribes from the Observable cleanly.

**Edit**: Based on your inclusion of HTML

If you have an error in your template, for example an unclosed tag:

`<div><div>` instead of `<div></div>` etc.

Or if the button to submit your form is left as the default type (submit), you may see this behavior.

```
<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">
```

Instead of:

```
<button (click)="submitForm()"> or <button type="submit" (click)="submitForm()">
```

Comment: Implemented all you mentioned, still it calling twice.

Comment: Put a console.log statement in the service in the if(personName!= undefined){...} block, something like "Setting headers", and then see which or whether both the headers message and the this.staff message appear on the console.

Comment: I'm having one master service, which calls the web service. Another method I call it from  component, where I call the master service. Since both the names I had given same it might got confused. So what ever mentioned here I had added to component. Do I need to add this in Master ?

Comment: The function names only have to be unique within the same class, so having the function in the component have the same name as the function in the service won't cause you a problem. See my earlier comment about adding another console.log in the service so you can see exactly what's being called twice.

Comment: Added console in both the methods, console message displays only once, But in browser it shows 2 service calls

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'console message displays only once, But in browser it shows 2 service calls'? You have a log statement in the component - do you see that only once? And you've added a log statement in the service - do you see that only once? What do you mean by 'in browser it shows 2 service calls'? How do you see this in the browser if not in the console log statements?

Comment: In browser, Network section it shows 2 service call for one click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149549/discussion-between-user630209-and-stephen-r-smith).